# How to apply custom jQuery UI button class on asp.net button

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have been trying to apply custom jquery ui css class on asp.net button but some how it is not working.

It works fine if i use my css class with button control as shown on attached image (first button). I need to use asp.net button for some reasons and would like to have it in same look as button control.

```
    <button id="btnLogin2"  type ="button" onserverclick ="btnLogin_Click"  runat="server" aria-disabled="false" role="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default cssbox-ui-corner-all cssbox-ui-corner-all:hover ui-button-text-icon-primary">
                  <span style="margin:-8px 94px" class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon cssbox-okbtn" ></span>
                  <span class="ui-button-text">Login</span>
    </button>
```

But css is not being applied on asp.net button.

```
   <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" Text=" Login " runat="server" CSSClass="cssbox-ui-corner-all cssbox-ui-corner-all:hover ui-button-text-icon-primary ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon cssbox-okbtn" />
```

**Custom CSS class**

```
    .cssbox-okbtn { 
        background-image: url('/images/icons/jquery_ui/ok.png') !important;     
    }

    .cssbox-ui-corner-all { 
        width:265px;
        border-radius: 0px; 
        background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #1A7BC9;
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1A7BC9 0px, #1A7BC9 100%);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#1A7BC9', endColorstr='#1A7BC9');/*For IE7-8-9*/ 
        border: 1px solid #1A7BC9;
        height: 35px;
        font-size: 12px;
    }

     .cssbox-ui-corner-all:hover { 
        border-radius: 0px; 
        background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #9CC8F7;
        color: #404040;
        border: 1px solid #9CC8F7;
        filter: none;
    }
```

**js script to apply okay button class**

```
    $(function () {
        $("input:submit").button({
            icons: { primary: 'cssbox-okbtn' }
        }).hide().after('<button>').next().button({
            icons:
            {
                primary: 'cssbox-okbtn'
            },
            label: $("input:submit").val()

        });
```

Second one is asp.net button.

[image]

Page Source

```
       <tr  style="height: 22px">
            <td align="center" colspan="1">
                <button onclick="__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnLogin2','')" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnLogin2" type="button" aria-disabled="false" role="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default cssbox-ui-corner-all cssbox-ui-corner-all:hover ui-button-text-icon-primary">
                  <span style="margin:-8px 94px" class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon cssbox-okbtn" ></span>
                  <span class="ui-button-text">Login</span>
                </button>

                <br />


                <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnLogin" value=" Login " id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnLogin" class="cssbox-ui-corner-all cssbox-ui-corner-all:hover ui-button-text-icon-primary ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon cssbox-okbtn" />

                </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: did you check css on client ? ( in page source ) is it same with server. Maybe u need to use client css property.

Comment: i have added the page source in my question.